# ERC777 upgradeable deployment error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit hardhat

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts, erc-777

Hi I could not deploy my ERC777 Upgradeable contract into Hardhat test network.

My ERC777 contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC777/ERC777Upgradeable.sol"; 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract ERC777 is
    OwnableUpgradeable,
    ERC777Upgradeable
{
    function initialize(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        address[] memory defaultOperators
    ) public initializer {
        __Ownable_init_unchained();
        __ERC777_init_unchained(name, symbol, defaultOperators);
    }
}
```

And my hardhat.config.ts:

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 7e6,
    },
    hardhat: {
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 7e6,
    },
  }
}
```

And my Hardhat test file:

```
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    user1Addr = accounts[1].address;
    user2Addr = accounts[2].address;
    user3Addr = accounts[3].address;
    LpToken777 = await ethers.getContractFactory('ERC777');
    lpToken777 = await upgrades.deployProxy(LpToken777, ["LpToken777", "LpToken777", [user1Addr, user2Addr, user3Addr]]);
```

Hardhat can compile my contracts no problem.

but right at the "upgrades.deployProxy" line above I got this error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Address: low-level delegate call failed'", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xf39Fd...
```

Any advice?

Reference:

OpenZeppelin ERC777 https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc777

Comment: your configuration is not a  EIP1559 standard. see https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference#mingasprice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Use one Hardhat plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-erc1820

`import "hardhat-erc1820";//for ERC777 deployment in hardhat.config.ts`

Then that plugin will somehow deploy an _ERC1820_REGISTRY contract for you at the default address: 0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I tried to use "hardhat-erc1820", but it didn't work well, so I changed it a little and it worked,here is my code ,

This is a full deployment of ERC1820 and ERC777 with hardhat :

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/ERC777